# I'm trying to run a basic hello world program using PyQt5 in Ubuntu 22.04 and Python3.10

Tags: pip, pyqt5, ubuntu-22.04, pythonqt

I got the warning and no GUI is opened .

> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
> Aborted (core dumped)

I have tried reinstall the PyQt5 but it did not work and even tried to install PyQt5

```
sudo apt install pip3-PyQt5
```

I got a warning

> WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Comment: What is unclear with `Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway`? Did you follow this instruction? Did it change anything?

Comment: Yeah I have used now the GUI is displaying but while displaying/excuting the program I'm getting an warning 
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread

Comment: Well now which steps did you take try overcomming this new error message? Please read [mre] and do not add details in comments: [edit] your question.